# Do you still work in / at the same company as earlier?

Tags: prepositions

I want to ask her if she works in / at the same company as she used to work earlier.

Which is correct? Any other improvements.

> Do you still work in / at the same company as earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**at**

Also, don't use "as earlier", use "as before" or just nothing — the meaning comes across through context.

"Do you still work at the same company?"
"Do you still work at the same company as before?"

Comment: Thanks. Can you kindly explain me why `as earlier` should not be used? I felt it odd to speak I admit, but any other issues. @codi6

Comment: I'm a native English speaker, so I, unfortunately, have no idea. It just sounds wrong to my ears.

Comment: Yes. Okay. Thanks btw.